# Adding extra input stops javascript from working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to edit some JavaScript code, but I have no experience with JavaScript.

I have this HTML form, and am trying to add an extra input to it:

```
<form method="post" action="php/subscribe.php" name="subscribeform" id="subscribeform">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address to get notified" id="subemail" />
      <input type="text" name="personname" placeholder="Enter your name" id="personname" />
      <input type="submit" name="send" value="Notify me" id="subsubmit" class="btn2" />
    </form>

    <!-- subscribe message -->
    <div id="mesaj"></div>
    <!-- subscribe message --> 
  </div>
```

The form subsequently pushes data to my PHP file. However, the theme I am using also features the following JavaScript file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('#subscribeform').submit(function(){

    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $("#mesaj").slideUp(750,function() {
    $('#mesaj').hide();

    $('#subsubmit')
        .after('')
        .attr('disabled','disabled');

    $.post(action, {
        email: $('#subemail').val()
        personname: $('#personname').val() // THIS STOPS THE FILE FROM WORKING


    },
        function(data){
            document.getElementById('mesaj').innerHTML = data;
            $('#mesaj').slideDown('slow');
            $('#subscribeform img.subscribe-loader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove()});
            $('#subsubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
            if(data.match('success') != null) $('#subscribeform').slideUp('slow');


        }
    );

    });

    return false;

});
```

Originally the theme only came with one input on the form for the email. However, when I try to add the `personname` input to both the form and the JavaScript file, it stops the JavaScript from working. Instead of the PHP rendering inside the main page, I am redirected to a blank PHP page which `echo`s the success message.

Like I said earlier I am extremely inexperienced in Javascript so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a comma there:

```
$.post(action, {
        email: $('#subemail').val(),  <--- Comma here
        personname: $('#personname').val() // THIS STOPS THE FILE FROM WORKING


    },
```

The Javascript inside those curlybrackets `{ ... }` (including the brackets) is what is known as an object. If you have seen JSON formatted data before, then it should be familiar to you. The syntax is basically key and value with colon separating them, and commas separating the key-value pairs.

Comment: Haha works perfectly. Thank you! Will accept as answer after the wait period is over.

Comment: @SK23 Great! Glad I could help out!

Comment: I see. I don't have much experience with programming outside of basic python. Is a javascript object similar to a python dictionary?

Comment: @SK23 Yes, I would say so. In Javascript it is also the closest thing you have to an associative array, if you are familiar with those. The arrays you access with a String-based key, rather than an index. In PHP for instance, they are really backed by a hashtable, and other languages have other ways to solve it. Associative arrays are quite popular, since they are so darn easy and convenient to use. ;)

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks again!